# Assumption testing for a large amount of individual regression models and averaging R-squared?

Tags: regression, linear, r-squared, assumptions, mean

I am running the following model for my thesis, a simple regression:

\begin{equation} 
    y_{i,t} = \alpha_t+\beta_tx_{p,t}+\varepsilon_{i,t}
\end{equation}

where Y is an observed variable (valuation multiple), where x is the harmonic mean of 10 similar companies' valuation multiples. Now, I have three "systems" from which I gather similar companies, over a time period of 15 years. The model will be run on a yearly basis (3x because 1 for each system) because I for each year obtain 1500 observations for y and x. Since I am using a simple regression, I will need to test whether or not there is a linear relation.

My question is sort of two-fold:

1) What is the best way to "structure" this assumption test, since I am running so many iterations? By assumption test, I mean testing whether the errors have zero mean, variance is constant etc.

2) My methodology follows other scientific papers, where for each system, the 
yearly $R^2$'s are averaged throughout the years - to obtain a final "goodness of fit" measure, i.e. which system is better. Is there any issues evolved in this? I am not much of a statistician, but it does seem quite ambigious...